# How to incorporate timeout and retries with context based session request in python

Tags: python, api, session, request, python-requests

In my current implementation, the application has a global session for all the requests with timeout and retries setting applied to it.

Now I want to make those requests context-based. But I am confused as to how to implement the timeout and retry setting to it. Do I have to repeat it for each request or can it be done in a much more defined manner?

Current scenario:

```
s = requests.Session()
r = Retry(total=5, backoff_factor=0.2, status_forcelist=[500, 501, 502, 503, 504])
s.mount("https://", HTTPAdapter(max_retries=r))
s.mount("http://", HTTPAdapter(max_retries=r))

s.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
```

Future implementation:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
```

How to define timeout and retry for the latter part in the best way for multiple calls?

Thanks in advance.